# Splitting string before and after a semi column [Kotlin]

Tags: string, kotlin, split

I have a json looking like this:

```
{"sortBy": "stuff:ASC"}
```

I am looping through each of the elements in a `ResponseEntity` body and I want to be able to extract the value of `sortby` before and after the semi column as I want their values individually. I would ideally use `aString.split(":")`, but I would perhaps need a regex to make sure that I am picking the right section of the string?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `split(";")`? In which use case don't you get the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`substringBefore`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before.html#substringbefore) and [`substringAfter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-after.html#substringafter). Like so:

```kotlin
val delimiter = ':'
val leftValue = aString.substringBefore(delimiter)
val rightValue = aString.substringAfter(delimiter)
```

Optionally, you can pass a value to be returned if the `delimiter` is not present, this value by default is the string itself. Like so:

```
val defaultLeftValue = "default"
val delimiter = ':'
val leftValue = aString.substringBefore(delimiter, defaultLeftValue)
```